# automatically organizing windows on large monitor

Tags: unity, windows, mouse, window-manager

I have 27" monitor running ubuntu 14.04.

When I work, I usually have more than 5 to 6 application (windows) open, which I organize in such a way that some part of that window ( application ) is just mouse click away, that help me quickly switch between different windows. This window are not organized in grid like structure but overlap one another, but at least some part of window is visible to enable switching with mouse easier.

I need to organize my windows many time while I work, which I want to automate.

i.e. I want all window to move such a way that "pressing some short cut key" all window should move such a way ( not resize ) that no matter which application is currently in focus, at least part of all other application is visible.

How do I achieve this ?

I am good/ok with python/shell scripts and can hack around, so a guide to how could I implement this myself is good enough for me.

I will share the result here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I accomplish a similar task using the tool `wmctrl`

command `wmctrl -l` will list the current windows

command `wmctrl -r  -e 0,X,Y,W,H will move/resize the window

Example:

```
wmctrl -i -r `wmctrl -l | grep "A Window Title" | tail -1 | cut -f1 -d" "` -e 0,1421,300,498,320
```

I have my script with a bunch of lines like the one above running on startup but I guess you could have a set of scripts and assign them to various hotkeys

**Edit**

To make your life a little easier move a window where you want it, run the tool `xwininfo` in a separate terminal and click on the window you want moved with wmctrl. xwininfo will output the height, width and all coordinates of the window you clicked on.

Comment: wooohoo...fantastic!! , lets build the script. :)